# How to create a JUnit 5 rule for Android activity?

Tags: java, kotlin, junit5

How to create a JUnit 5 @rule for Android activity?

**JUnit 4**

```
@get:Rule
    val mActivityRule: ActivityTestRule<GeralActivity> = ActivityTestRule(GeralActivity::class.java)
```

**JUnit 5**

```
???
```

Comment: Before or after what?

Comment: I've fixed my question

Comment: @user4412879 you got any solution?